# Batch file to run an Android app in emulator

Tags: android, apk

`compile.bat`:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;H:\Source\Program\sdk\tools;
set PATH=%PATH%;H:\Source\Program\sdk\platform-tools;
cd sdk\tools
emulator -avd emulator2
adb wait-for-device  
cd sdk\platform-tools
adb install -r SP.apk
```

Here is my batch file to run a .apk into an emulator. It is from a CD, my adviser wants to run my app in his computer using my CD. My SDK folder is also in the CD and is the same directory with my `compile.bat`. Is my setting of path correct? Also there is an error when I test the `compile.bat` from the cd, it says `too many files specified; only take APK file and verifier file`.

The `adb install` command also become like this `adb install -r SP.apk apk P.apk T_ROOTPROJECT_NAME-debug.apk`. I only want to install `SP.apk` in the emulator.

When I run the commands in cmd, not in a batch file it is working.

Also I want to know how to enable the camera in my laptop to the emulator. My app requires the camera to run.

Can someone help me please? I am begging you. I need this tomorrow its for my graduation. Thank you.

Comment: You most efficient course of action will probably be to try to find a physical device for the demo.

Comment: my adviser does not want any device. he wants to show it in an emulator.